# How to attach a file using cURL?

Tags: php, file, curl, zip, email-attachments

I am creating a zip folder in which I need to attach to an email. Attaching the zip folder is not working.

I included three files below that work together:

The SEND file is where the ajax sends the files to. Then there is a fileUpload.php file that uploads single files and generates the `$filename` variable array for all the files uploaded. This is where the zip folder gets created and where I attempt to attach it with `$message`.

The COMMUNICATION CLASS is used to send emails. Originally, the zip folder was created/attached here. For some reason, I can't figure out how to get the two files to work together, outside of what it already does.

The TEMPLATE file is where email html and css are contained. Also are the {variables}. This is where the filename and message variables are. Though, filename should be all that is required.

The zip folder is being created. It is just not attaching.

Does anyone see why when the zip is created that it isn't attaching to the email? Specifically, this part of the code is where I am trying to do it:

```
$message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create($target_dir . $filename[0] . ".zip",
    pathinfo("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
    $filename[0] . ".zip");
```

SEND FILE

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'classes/Communication.php';
require 'fileUpload.php';

$first_name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES));
$last_name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES));
$email = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$zip = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['zip']));
$company = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['company'], ENT_QUOTES));
$details = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES));
$file = null;

require_once '../config.php';

    /************************ Start to Company ******************************/
    $placeholders = ['{first_name}',
        '{last_name}',
        '{phone}',
        '{zip}',
        '{company}',
        '{description}',
        '{interest}',
        '{email}',
        '{lead_owner}',
        '{lead_assign}'
    ];

    $values = [
        htmlentities($_POST['first_name']),
        htmlentities($_POST['last_name']),
        htmlentities($_POST['phone']),
        htmlentities($_POST['zip']),
        htmlentities($_POST['company']),
        nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['description'])),
        htmlentities($_POST['interest']),
        htmlentities($_POST['email']),
        $lead_owner = htmlentities($_POST['leadOwner']),
        $lead_assign = htmlentities($_POST['leadAssign']),
    ];

    $template = str_replace($placeholders, $values, file_get_contents("templates/quote_to_domain.html"));

    $files = null;
    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {

        if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] == 1) {
            $error = "The file {$_POST['first_name']} attempted to upload is too large. Contact them for an alternate way to send this file.";
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", "$error", $template);
        }

        $date = new DateTime();
        $fu = new fileUpload();
        $filename = $fu->upload();
        $uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
        $extensions = ['pdf','jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
        //file_put_contents('file_type_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($uploadedFileTypes, true), FILE_APPEND);
        $target_dir = "uploads/";

        $differentExtensions = array_diff($uploadedFileTypes, $extensions);
        if (count($differentExtensions) > 0) {
            //file_put_contents('file_norm_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r('There were other types of files uploaded', true), FILE_APPEND);  
            $f = new ZipArchive();
            $zip = $f->open($target_dir . $filename[0] . ".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
            if ($zip) {
                for ($index = 0; $index < count($filename); $index++) {
                    $f->addFile($target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$index]), basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$index]));
                }
                $f->close();

                $message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create($target_dir . $filename[0] . ".zip",
                    pathinfo("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
                    $filename[0] . ".zip");
                //$template = str_replace("{filename}", $message, $template);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Could not zip the files.");
                $msg = "Could not zip the files.";
                echo json_encode(['status_code' => 500,
                'message' => $msg]);
            }
        } else {
            $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
            foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
                //print_r($template);
                $out .= "<li><a href='/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
            }
            $out .= '</ul>';
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
        }

        foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
            foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($value)) {
                    //echo "name is empty!";
                    $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
                }   
                if ($file['error'][$key] != 4) {
                    //echo "error code is 4";
                }
            }
        }
        clearstatcache();
    }
    $to_company = Communication::mail_api($_POST, $filename, $template, 0);
```

Then here is the communication class. Originally, the zip code was in here (and still is). I can't figure out how to get the two files to work together as they should have.

COMMUNICATION CLASS

```
class Communication
{

    public static function mail_api(Array $msg, Array $filename = null, $template = null, $recipient = false, $attachment = null)
    {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $config = array();
        $message = array();
        $message['to'] = !$recipient ? $email_to_send_to : $msg['email'];
        $message['h:Reply-To'] = !$recipient ? $msg['email'] : '';
        $message['subject'] = isset($msg['subject']) ? $msg['subject'] : '';

        if ($attachment) {
            try {
                if (!file_exists($attachment)) {
                    throw new Exception("File $attachment not found!");
                }
                $parts = explode('/', $attachment);
                $filenames = end($parts);
                $message['attachment[0]'] = curl_file_create($attachment,
                    pathinfo($attachment, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
                    $filenames);
                file_put_contents('log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . "Attachment added: \n", FILE_APPEND); //here

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                file_put_contents('error_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . "Error adding attachment: \n" . print_r($e, 1), FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }

        $message['html'] = $template;

        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['api_url']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'o:tracking-clicks: false'
            ));

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:{$config['api_key']}");
            $self = new Communication();

            if (!empty($file) && !$recipient && count($filename) > 1) {

                $f = new ZipArchive();
                $zip = $f->open('uploads/' . $filename[0] . ".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
                if ($zip) {
                    for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); $index++) {
//                        echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";
                        //$f->addFile($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$index], $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index]);
                        $f->addFile($target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$index]), basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$index]));
                    }
                    $f->close();

        $message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip",
                        pathinfo("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
                        $filename[0] . ".zip");
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Could not zip the files.");
                }
//                $message['html'] = str_replace("{filename}", "A file was uploaded. You can download the file from: <a href='/php/uploads/{$file['uploadedFile']['name']}.zip'>{$file['uploadedFile']['name']}</a>", $message['html']);

            } elseif (count($filename) == 1) {
                $message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create("uploads/{$filename}",
                    pathinfo("uploads/{$filename}", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
                    $filename);
            }


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $resp = json_decode($result);
            file_put_contents('communication_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}] " . "Log for {$message['to']}: \n" . print_r(json_encode($resp) . "\n\n" . print_r($message,1), 1), FILE_APPEND);
            // print_r($resp);
            if (isset($resp->id))
                return true;
            return false;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            file_put_contents('error_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . "Error for {$message['to']}: \n" . print_r($e, 1), FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
```

Then the template, which is an email that sends the file link or attachment (though attachment not sending):

TEMPLATE

```
<tr>
  <td> {filename} </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><i>{message}</i></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the question really is _"How do I pass a file using cURL"_ since I don't see anything about sending emails in your code but I do see some cURL code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, that does sound like a more accurate question title. I will try to update.